# Launching mpi4py on Windows machine

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I've got a problem trying to use `MPI` for Python on `Windows 7, 64bit.`

I've downloaded `Python` 3.4(also tried with 2.7 - the same error) and installed library from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py (mpi4py‑1.3.1.win32‑py3.4.exe to be exact). And when I proceed this code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
```

I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENRc7.png

I don't really know, why the paths are "`**d:**\build\mpi4py..."`, because there is no partition called d:\ in my computer.